# Redirect from home page to post list page?

Tags: redirect, apache

There is a site at `http://theprimarkonlineshop.com` that I want to be redirected to `http://theprimarkonlineshop.com/category/blog` when a user enters the site. 
I've tried some stuff like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^$ 
RewriteRule . http://theprimarkonlineshop.com/category/blog/ [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't work.

Also there are some redirections that were put into `.htaccess` by WordPress

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I guess they should remain as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirect/

1. Install above plugin
2. Create a page
3. Add custom field: redirect of a value of http://theprimarkonlineshop.com/category/blog
4. Set page you have created to the sites homepage.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect):

```
<?php wp_redirect( 'http://theprimarkonlineshop.com/category/blog/', 301 ); exit; ?>
```

put it in a custom template and set it as your homepage.php file or you can do this from your settings also.